# Do Google Drive Realtime APIs support partial response?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-api

I'm using the Java Google Client Library to access a Realtime API method (namely, the "get" one). It seems to me that, unlike the vast majority of the other Google APIs, Realtime API methods do not support partial responses. I tried with:

```
HttpResponse response = drive.realtime().get(fileId).setFields("revision").executeMedia();
String responseString = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(response.getContent()));
```

`responseString` contains the whole response, while I was expecting a (much smaller)

```
{
  "revision":3240
}
```

Has anyone experienced that?